# How do i grab HTML Checkbox Form Values and check if the Value of the ID is the same as the User_id to auto increment Votes

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

so i have a Survey where the Clients are going to Input Names.
We will share the Link with other People and they can Vote several Names.
The Endgoal is to show them the voted winner.
I have trouble to get the Value of the checkbox, and to  Auto-increment it. I checked with print_r($_POST) if i get a boolean value which i do.

So my Array understands that it is checked or unchecked.
The name of the Checkbox is an Array and the Value should be the ID of the User.

I am trying to compare the UserID with the Value of the Checkbox and if it is checked it should increment a column in my database which is by default 0.
So this way each time a Form is submitted it checks who got checked and increments the value that Person got so i can later Display the Votes.

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Selection;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Selections extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $selections = Selection::all();
        //return Selection::Name();
        return view('welcome', [
            'selections' => $selections
        ]);
        //return Selection::$table('Name');
    }
    public function create(){
        return view('list.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        //$selection = new Selection;
        //$selection-> Vorname = $request->input('vorname');
        //$selection-> Name = $request->input('name');
        //$selection->save();

        $selection = Selection::create([
            'Vorname'=>$request->input('vorname'),
            'Name' =>$request->input('name'),
            'Auswertung'=>$request->get('Auswertung')
        ]);
        return redirect('/');

    }
    public function update(Request $request){
        $selection = Selection::update([
            'Auswertung'=>$request->input('Auswertung')
        ]);
    }
    public function danke(){
        return view('danke');
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Selection extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='selection';
    protected $fillable = ['Vorname','Name'];
}
```

The Form:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h1 class="headline">Wahlmöglichkeiten</h1>
                        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="/danke" id="wahl">
            @csrf

        @foreach($selections as $selection)
            <div class="form-check" >
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="selected" name="selected[]" value="{{$selection->id}}" >
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    {{$selection->Vorname}},{{$selection->Name}}
                </label>

        @endforeach
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
                </p>
        </form>
@endsection
```

My Database Table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSelectionTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('selection', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('Vorname')->nullable();
            $table->string('Name')->nullable();
            $table->integer('Auswertung')->default(0);

            // $table->boolean('picked')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('selection');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did:

```
public function update(Request $request){
        foreach($request->input('votes') as $vote) {
            $selection = Selection::find($vote);
            $selection->Auswertung++;
            $selection->save();
        }
        return redirect('danke');
    }
```

Turns out when i use the find method it gets the primal key and gets into the column to increment up.